# Query reflection in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, reflection, evaluation

Let's say I have a SQLite table with a column that stores queries, like so:

```
sqlite> create table foo (queries text);
sqlite> insert into foo values ('select "Hello";');
```

Is there any way to retrieve the stored `select "Hello";` out of `foo`and then evaluate it (as a subquery) *in the same query*?

The Lisp-y equivalent would be something like: `(apply (select-from-foo))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Queries are compiled by `sqlite3_prepare` before they are executed.